# Change the font size/font color/background color of a label on ribbon in vsto outlook add-in

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I am writing a outlook addin using vsto and c#
I have a xml ribbon bar containing some information that I need to show to the user. For example the xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAddIns" label="NEW_TAB">
        <group id="StatsGroup" label="Statistics">
          <labelControl id="lblSmallText" label="Stats are:  "/>
          <labelControl id="lblNormalText" label="Dollars Saved"/>
          <labelControl id="lblBigText"       label="$12345"/>
          <!--
          <labelControl id="lblNormalText" label="as of today"/>
          -->          
        </group>        
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>  
</customUI>
```

I need to INCREASE the font size of one of the labelControl OR alternatively at least be able to change the font or background color to bring the user's attention to it.
I tried adding font attributes in the xml but it is having no effect.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems not possible at this moment - 2017.06.29 ..... Maybe in future Microsoft will allow such a modifications

Comment: Are there any other controls for showing some text which can be placed on the ribbon and allow changing font/font color/background color?

I have found toggle button, can the background color of toggle button be changed?

Answer (score 1):

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) doesn't provide anything for that. Read more about all available attributes and callbacks in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

If you need to show a custom UI to a user in Outlook consider using Outlook Form Regions instead, see [Creating Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information. In that case you will be able to use any .net controls.

Comment: Are there any other controls for showing some text which can be placed on the ribbon and allow changing font/font color/background color?

I have found toggle button, can the background color of toggle button be changed?

Comment: No, the Fluent UI controls don't provide anything for that.