# Changing Font in Access Custom Ribbon

Tags: ms-access, fonts, arabic, ribbonx

I'm working on an Urdu/Arabic project in Microsoft Access and want to build custom ribbon (using xml code) for navigating for different forms. Ribbon labels will be in Urdu/Arabic so need to set a font which have better readibility in said languages. I search over internet but couldn't find an answer to my query. How can we change font for labels in a custom ribbon in Access?

Best Regards,

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44825629/change-the-font-size-font-color-background-color-of-a-label-on-ribbon-in-vsto-ou

Answer (score 0):

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon) doesn't provide anything for setting a font for its controls. You can read more about the ribbon UI in the following articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Thanks. Is there no other way around to do this?

Comment: You can create a form with your own controls.